# Different results using C# HMAC Rfc2898DeriveBytes and C++ Crypto++ PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC

Tags: c#, c++, crypto++

I'm trying to encrypt data using C# and read it using C++ Crypto++ library. I want to use AES encryption with Key an IV so the first step is to generate Key and IV using HMAC.

Here is the C# code to generate a key of 32 bytes:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace DeriveKeyCSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string password = "sdHBDHC^BGGijvn";
            int niter = 1000;
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, new byte[13] { (byte)73, (byte)118, (byte)97, (byte)110, (byte)32, (byte)77, (byte)101, (byte)100, (byte)118, (byte)101, (byte)100, (byte)101, (byte)118 },
                niter, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1);
            byte[] derivedKey = rfc.GetBytes(32);
        }
    }
}
```

this generates a derivedKey with values: 237, 130, 48, 114 ......

and here is the C++ code:

```
#include <cryptopp/hmac.h>
#include <cryptopp/sha.h>
#include <cryptopp/pwdbased.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main()
{
    byte password[] = "sdHBDHC^BGGijvnH";
    size_t plen = strlen((const char*)password);

    byte salt[] = { 73, 118, 97, 110, 32, 77, 101, 100, 118, 101, 100, 101, 118 };
    size_t slen = sizeof(salt);

    byte keyByte[] = "sdHBDHC^BGGijvnH";
    int lenKey = sizeof(keyByte) - 1; // remove \n
    byte derivedKey[32];
    PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<SHA1> pbkdf2;
    pbkdf2.DeriveKey(derivedKey, sizeof(derivedKey), 0, keyByte, lenKey, salt, sizeof(salt), 1000);
}
```

this generates a derivedKey with values: 118, 142, 106, 94 ......

I checked functions signatures and parameters, I tested removing the "\n" of the C++ char array but I can't get the same derived key in both languages.

I tested a lot of stackoverflow code but I couldn't find a working solution.

Comment: You could check which generated hash (if any!) is correct [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html)

Comment: You have different passwords between C# and C++ (last has additional H at the end).

Comment: @Evk Hehe, I am blind!

Comment: @PaulSanders if someone's blind it's not you but OP ;) But that happens with everyone.